# Startup Settings In Chrome Disabled

Tags: google-chrome, browser, settings, startup

Today when I turn on my laptop I haven't got the tabs which I have left opened in Google Chrome under start up settings (Continue where I Left Off).

It is disturbing as I have opened some tabs from time to time. It is very time-consuming to re-open all those tabs again by seeing history. If anyone knows the solution please tell me.

I have attached picture [here](http://salmanshaikh1.blogspot.com/2013/12/on-startup-settings-in-chrome-disabled.html) also.

Comment: This is a useful question. It should be moved to http://superuser.com rather than closed.

Comment: Here is an equivalent question at superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/590726/why-i-cant-change-on-startup-chrome-option

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that the setting is enforced by your admin.

Check Settings - On Startup
Is the "Continue where I left off" radio button selectable?
Is the radio button "Open a specific page or set of pages" selected?
Are there yellow marks around it?
When you mouse-over the marks you see "*This setting is enforced by your administrator.*"

This is controlled by the registry keys under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Google/Chrome
```

(try HKEY_CURRENT_USER if this does not work for you)

[RestoreOnStartup](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#RestoreOnStartup)

```
5 = Open New Tab Page

1 = Restore the last session

4 = Open a list of URLs

Example value: 0x00000004 (Windows), 4 (Linux), 4 (Mac)
```

> "Action on startup Data type:
>
> Integer (REG_DWORD)
>
> Windows registry location:
>
> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RestoreOnStartup
>
> Mac/Linux preference name: RestoreOnStartup
>
> Supported on: Google Chrome (Linux, Mac, Windows) since version 8
> Google Chrome OS (Google Chrome OS) since version 11
>
> Supported features: Can Be Recommended: Yes, Dynamic Policy Refresh:
> Yes, Per Profile: Yes
>
> Description: Allows you to specify the behavior on startup. If you
> choose 'Open New Tab Page' the New Tab Page will always be opened when
> you start Google Chrome. If you choose 'Restore the last session', the
> URLs that were open last time Google Chrome was closed will be
> reopened and the browsing session will be restored as it was left.
> Choosing this option disables some settings that rely on sessions or
> that perform actions on exit (such as Clear browsing data on exit or
> session-only cookies). If you choose 'Open a list of URLs', the list
> of 'URLs to open on startup' will be opened when a user starts Google
> Chrome. If you enable this setting, users cannot change or override it
> in Google Chrome. Disabling this setting is equvalent to leaving it
> not configured. The user will still be able to change it in Google
> Chrome.

Comment: If the setting is applied you can still use the "pin tab" feature to get a similar result.

Comment: Changing the registry setting worked for me. Thank you hero.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` didn't work for me - I had to add it to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Also note that the effect is immediate - if you refresh the Settings page, you should see it change (no restart required to confirm the change)

Comment: Note that this situation happened to me on a Windows 10 machine that is not part of a domain at all - so there is no group policy in place - seems like a Google Chrome bug to me.
The behavior started when I created a second google profile - both profiles had the RestoreOnStartup setting set to 4 - "open a list of URLs" despite the setting having been to restore the last session prior to creating the second profile.

Comment: This has been submitted to Google as an issue using in-chrome "Report an Issue..."

Comment: It works to me. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Google/Chrome , if no edit possible, open the command prompt as administrator and run regedit then change.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with v116. My PC is under domain and the above steps don't let me override the policy.